# How to avoid deletion of more than 1 row per request with trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I want to write a *trigger* which *denies* *deletion* of more than 1 row per request

Is it possible to write such trigger? If yes, can you help with an idea or code?

I am using oracle database 11g and writing in sqldeveloper

**Orders** Table

```
id
detail
orderdate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this (multi-row deletes are more efficient than single-row deletes), but you could use a compound trigger for this purpose, e.g.:

```
create table mytable (id number);

create or replace trigger one_row_per_delete
  for delete on mytable
  compound trigger

  row_count integer;

  before statement is
  begin
    row_count := 0;
  end before statement;

  before each row is
  begin
    row_count := row_count + 1;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    if row_count > 1 then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot delete more than one row per statement');
    end if;
  end after statement;

end one_row_per_delete;
```

Tested:

```
insert into mytable values (1);

1 row inserted.

insert into mytable values (2);

1 row inserted.

insert into mytable values (3);

1 row inserted.

delete mytable where id = 1;

1 row deleted.

delete mytable;

ORA-20000: Cannot delete more than one row per statement
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.ONE_ROW_PER_DELETE", line 18
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.ONE_ROW_PER_DELETE'
```

Comment: By the way, I want to delete only one row, because it was just assessment task

Comment: In that case, you should really have tried to do it yourself first - by getting me to do your homework for you, you have just robbed yourself of part of the benefit of getting an education, and the enjoyment that comes with solving a problem for yourself. Best wishes.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - *"I'm not sure why you would want to do this "* Just another example of teachers teaching students bad practice, because they have to cover the whole language.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform it with a trigger, for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER denies_delete_trg
BEFORE DELETE
   ON table_name
DECLARE
   v_count_elements NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_count_elements
   FROM table_name
   WHERE contitions_of_delete;

   IF v_count_elements > 0 THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Too rows to delete.'); 
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored      PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: @JustAhead: did you really just copy and paste this answer and run it as is? In future, please make sure you understand a suggestion before you do anything with it. As is, this answer is incorrect, and even if it was syntactically correct (which it isn't), will still not work anyway.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp ok, in future I will mention it, by the way, I have changed table name and column name, and I run it because actually I don't understand complex written triggers, what I've learned was so easy

Comment: I've compiled the trigger in a personal database and doesn't throw any error as you say. I'd thought that you have a condition on the delete (I don't know why) and put it on the where the condition of the counting query. If you had read and understood the suggestion, you would have seen where the error occurs. I accept that it is not the solution to the problem, what I do not accept is that as @JeffreyKemp indicates, make a copy and paste without understanding what you're doing.